# Listing mysqli table entries in html using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm a beginner and I can't figure out for the life of me how to list products from a mysqli table on a webpage using php. Currently I just manage to get the first row to repeat for the number of rows that exist in the table using the following code:

```
<?php
  $p_sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
  $p_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $p_sql);
  $productData = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
  $num = mysqli_num_rows($p_query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <?php print "There are currently $num rows in the table<P>";
    for ($row=0; $row<$num; $row++){
      $name = $productData["product_name"];
      echo "$name <br>";
    };
  ?>
```

I know within my for loop I don't include `$row` but I don't know how to properly include it. Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using your `for()` loop, use a `while()` loop with your `$productData = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query, MYSQL_ASSOC)`

```
<?php
$p_sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
$p_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $p_sql);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($p_query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php print "There are currently $num rows in the table<P>";

while($productData = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo $productData["product_name"]."<br />";
};
?>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks! It works now, but it doesn't show the first row in the table, just the rest? :/

Comment: Make sure to remove the 1st `$productData = mysqli_fetch_array($p_query, MYSQL_ASSOC)` that was after `$p_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $p_sql);` at the top. You only want to call it in the while loop, if not it will move it to the 2nd returned row before you do the loop.